# lua 64-bit transitioning issue

Tags: 64-bit, lua, 32-bit, 32bit-64bit

I really hope there is some help to get on this subject. Has anyone ever used lua in an application that needs to have both 32-bit and 64-bit support? We are currently transitioning to 64-bit but are having trouble with client compiled lua scripts that we can't recompile ourselves using the 64-bit version. So in effect we need to be able to load bytecode files compiled using 32-bit lua in a 64-bit application. When we try to do so we receive an error message:

virtual machine mismatch in test.bin.lua: size of size_t is 8 but read 4

Well of course this is a clear 64bit transitioning problem. The hard thing is just to figure out what to do about it without the ability to recompile the binaries.

Thanks

Comment: note that loading bytecode is discouraged.  safer and more portable is to load source code.

Answer (score 3):

It's not hard to adapt lundump.c to read 32-bit bytecode files. I've posted a roadmap for this in the Lua mailing list. If you have problems, please send me email.

Comment: I'm interested in this subject. Do you have a to your mailing list post?

Comment: Thanks. It was actually really trivial since I just had to modify `lundump.c` to be able to deal with `size_t` sizes of 4 bytes *and* 8 bytes. After this modification the 32-bit versions of my program are now magically able to run bytecode produced by the 64-bit version and vice versa. Of course it won't work on 32-bit if there is really a string with more than 2^32 bytes of data but that's rather unlikely I guess :) Another thing I had to change was the `Instruction` typedef from `unsigned long` to `unsigned int` because instructions should be 32-bit. Note that I'm still on Lua 5.0.2.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for the feedback. Consider updating to Lua 5.0.3, which is the last release of Lua 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [LuaDec: "LuaDec is a decompiler for the Lua language."](http://luadec.luaforge.net/) I don't know much about it, and the website states that it targets Lua 5.0.2. So, it may not work out of the box, but it's better than starting from scratch.