# Questions about compiling Lua files

Tags: compiler-construction, lua, luac

I want to compile my lua files to LuaC (myfile.luac). I'm using the Scite for compiling Lua.
I haven't started until now, I heard, that I cannot compile my lua files to a 64 bit binary luaC file on a 32 bit system.
So how can I compile lua to 32 bit and 64 bit luaC on a 32 bit system, windows xp?

Btw, are there any tipps for using Luac?
And, can my files be decompiled? I hope not ...

Answer (score 1):

About the 32- vs 64-bit issue, see [lua 64-bit transitioning issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725291/lua-64-bit-transitioning-issue/3729403#3729403) .

Precompiled Lua scripts can be (partially) decompiled. See http://luaforge.net/projects/luadec51/ .

What kind of tips do you have in mind?